# Passing values with condition in intent?

Tags: android

I want to send some data from activity `A` to activity `B` ONLY in case I have entered some values in activity `A`. So, in `A` I have

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
i.putExtra("email", email);
i.putExtra("password", password);
startActivity(i);
```

In `B`:

```
EditText login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
if(!(getIntent().getExtras().getString("email").isEmpty())){
    emailText = getIntent().getExtras().getString("email");
    login.setText(emailText);
    if(!(getIntent().getExtras().getString("password").isEmpty())){
        passwordText = getIntent().getExtras().getString("password");
        password.setText(passwordText);
    } 
}
```

But when I run my project, I get "Sorry, the application has stopped unexpectedly..." In LogCat I get a `NullPointerException`.

What is my mistake?

Comment: which line returns  null pointer exception ?

Comment: Provide the full stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getIntent().getExtras().getString("email")` will return `null` if "email" extra is not defined.

So:

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("email") != null){
    emailText = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
    login.setText(emailText);
    if(getIntent().getStringExtra("password") != null){
        passwordText = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");
        password.setText(passwordText);
    } 
}
```

**Updated:** there are no extras at all so `getIntent().getExtras()` will already return `null`. Updated above code to handle that.

Comment: Ah yes. There are no extras at all. Updated the post.

Comment: I also though about that. Thank you for code, for helping at all ;)

Answer (score 1):

`isEmpty()` only returns true if the string is length 0. If the string does not exist, a null value will be provided and you cannot call `isEmpty()` on a null string. That will throw a null exception.

you can change it to

```
if (!(getIntent().getExtras().getString("email") == null )
```

Answer (score 0):

`getIntent()` or `getIntent().getExtras()`  or `getIntent().getExtras().getString("email")` or `getIntent().getExtras().getString("password")` or `findViewById(R.id.login)` or `findViewById(R.id.password)` returns null

edit: added 2 more options

Comment: if you have any query regarding question then please ask in comments not in answer.

Comment: please, read the question ... "What is my mistake?" and this is an answer

Comment: but you can post it in comments also.